# NSPredicate on UUID field returns empty array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uuid, cloudkit

I have a method that fetches some entities from core data based on a predicate (see below). It passes the unit tests and it works most of the time in the actual code.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<T>()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "myUUID.UUIDString == %@", someUUIDString)
request.entity = entityDescription
```

Then I made a CloudKit integration using `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`. Now the same method, still fetching core data entities, has stopped returning entities. I have triple checked that I am passing in a valid uuid string that definitely exists in core data. It returns no results.

After a lot of debugging, I worked out that if I use the below code, it works. How is this even possible given that the field is a UUID and not a string?

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<T>()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "myUUID == %@", someUUIDString)
request.entity = entityDescription
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction project?

Comment: 1. How are you storing the UUID in Core Data model - i.e. as what type? 2. What is the `@NSManaged` line in your `NSManagedObject` subclass for this attribute?

Comment: At time of writing, UUID is not a supported data type for CloudKit (even though since iOS 11, Core Data has begun supporting it). As such, do you store your UUID in CloudKit as an NSString using the ".uuidString" property? And is the field in CloudKit called "myUUID"? If so, then such a predicate should succeed if you pass in 'someUUIDString' and it matches an entry.